# Handling empty case with tuple filtering and unpacking

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

I have a situation with some parallel lists that need to be filtered based on the values in one of the lists.  Sometimes I write something like this to filter them:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
listb = [7, 8, 9]
filtered_a, filtered_b = zip(*[(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(lista, listb) if a < 3])
```

This gives `filtered_a == (1, 2)` and `filtered_b == (7, 8)`

However, changing the final condition from `a < 3` to `a < 0` causes an exception to be raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I know why this is happening: the list comprehension is empty, so it's like calling `zip(*[])`, which is like `zip()`, which just returns an empty list which cannot be unpacked into separate filtered_a and filtered_b iterables.

Is there a better (shorter, simpler, more pythonic) filtering function that handles the empty case? In the empty case, I would expect filtered_a, and filtered_b to be empty iterables so any following code could remain unchanged.

Comment: What do you expect `filtered_a` and `filtered_b` to be in this case? `None`? Empty tuples/lists?

Comment: @TomDalton - Forgot that, thanks.  Added to the question now: "In the empty case, I would expect filtered_a, and filtered_b to be empty iterables so any following code could remain unchanged."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply *short-circuit* with the default values:

```
filtered_a, filtered_b = zip(*[(a, b) for a, b in zip(lista, listb) if a < 0]) or ([], [])
print(filtered_b, filtered_a)
# [] []
```

For Python 3, you'll need to call `list` on the iterator returned by `zip` so the first operand can be evaluated as an empty list (not an iterator), else the default value is never reached even when the iterator is potentially empty since `bool(iter([]))` is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
listb = [7, 8, 9]

filtered_abs = ((a, b) for (a, b) in zip(lista, listb) if a < 3])

for a, b in filtered_abs:
    do_thing(a, b)
```