# How to unpack result of `zip` which might be empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I have a generator for tuples which I want to use like this:

```
def pairs():
    yield from [("key1", 2), ("key2", 4), ("key3", 6)]

keys, values = zip(*pairs())
```

Works like a charm, but now `pairs()` can also yield nothing resulting in an expression equivalent to

```
keys, values = []
```

Is it possible to force the output of `zip` to have a given dimension in a nice single expression?

What I'd like to have is something like this:

```py
>>> keys, values = magic_extender(zip(*pairs()), 2)
>>> keys, values
((), ())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling empty case with tuple filtering and unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468683/handling-empty-case-with-tuple-filtering-and-unpacking)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469369/safe-unpack-empty-tuple-array or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274875/returning-none-or-a-tuple-and-unpacking

Comment: Well, all these are answers but very longish and complicated. The most elegant way would be `keys, values = tuple(zip(*pairs())) or ((), ())` - did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

***My Python version (3.7)***

I suggest that if you working with keys and values you should use dictionary's
and then the solution is not hard...

### solution

```py
def pairs():
    """
    documentation of the function.

    Returns
    -------
        dict
            The function returns dictionary...
    """
    yield {"key1": 2, "key2": 4, "key3": 6}


def main():
    pair = dict(next(pairs()))
    keys, values = list(pair.keys()), list(pair.values())
    print(keys, values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this solution the output will be:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3'] [2, 4, 6]
```

and if the dictionary is empty the output will be:

```
[] []
```

Comment: This would be a nice approach if I could avoid the tuples as part of the story - in my question `pairs()` is just an example for an iterable returning tuples.

Comment: This does not answer the question even remotely